# Puppet: cannot load such file -- semantic_puppet

Tags: installation, puppet

I am getting below error while enabling the puppet agent. I got this error during installation process.

```
[root@rgenupula1c puppet-enterprise-2019.0.2-el-7-x86_64]# /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin/puppet agent --enable
Ignoring executable-hooks-1.3.2 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine executable-hooks --version 1.3.2
Ignoring gem-wrappers-1.3.2 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine gem-wrappers --version 1.3.2
Ignoring executable-hooks-1.3.2 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine executable-hooks --version 1.3.2
Ignoring gem-wrappers-1.3.2 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine gem-wrappers --version 1.3.2
cannot load such file -- semantic_puppet
[root@rgenupula1c puppet-enterprise-2019.0.2-el-7-x86_64]#
```

Comment: Had the same problem, which turned out to be caused by RVM. The workaround that worked for me: `sudo mv /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh{,.save}` and then invoke Puppet in a new shell.

Answer (score 2):

`semantic_puppet` requires `executable-hooks-1.3.2` and `gem-wrappers-1.3.2`.  However both of these cannot be loaded because - according to the error message - their 'extensions are not built'.

This can happen when you have multiple rubies installed and the gems get confused between them.  You can fix things using `gem pristine --all` as long as you are in the correct ruby environment.

Depending on your puppet install, and your local ruby install, there might be different ways to specify which ruby you are using.  However, you might like to try something like:

```
PATH=/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin:$PATH
export PATH
sudo gem pristine --all
```

Comment: This solution didn't work for me, I am using ruby which is pre installed in puppet environment

Answer (score 1):

In my case, semantic_puppet was not installed in the ruby environment which was set default to puppet. This is how I made it work :

1. Stop running server :

   $ sudo service pe-puppetserver stop
2. Run the following command :

   $ puppetserver gem install semantic_puppet
3. Restart puppet server :

   $ sudo service pe-puppetserver restart

**Make sure your environment variables are pointing to /opt/puppetlabs/bin when you run this command by super user.**

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the game - but - if you are here because of issues with puppet agent.. it might be because you have another copy of ruby on your system and it's getting in the way of the one that puppet installs. Check your path and you might see **rvm** there or something else of that ilk.

If you can uninstall any other ruby installs then this might fix the problem.

If you can't uninstall them then do what you can to make sure that the puppet ruby install is first on the path.